# How to find index of string in List

Tags: python, list, indexing

Sorry if this is a noob question. But I am new to programming so I am still learning.

I have a string

```
string = "Hello Bye Hi"
```

I split it up:

```
new_list_string = string.split
```

output:

```
["Hello", "Bye", "Hi"]
```

My question is how can I use this newly generated list, for example.

if I do this:

```
 new_list_string[1]
```

I don't get "Bye", instead I get an error:

```
builtins.TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `string.split()` you need to add parens to call the method, also try to avoid using `string` as a variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is you did `string.split`, and not `string.split()`

Deeper explanation:
when you do `string.split`, you never actually *call* `split`. Therefore, it returns the function rather than the list. You need to call it with the syntax `string.split()`

Comment: ohh.. wait let me try that. I'll let u know what I get.

Answer (score 0):

try `new_list_string = string.split()` 
then you should be able to access

```
new_list_string[0]
new_list_string[1]
new_list_string[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, you can use `index(v)` to find a value's index :).

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
new_list_string()[1]
```

although it is better not to use string as a variable, because it is the name of a python module. Anyway, you should use...

```
s.split()
```